# Call a private attribute

Tags: java

How can i call a variable (private double balance) from a superclass in subclass if that variable is private in java?

```
public class Account {

private double bal;
```

}

I need to call it from this subclass:

```
public class SavingAccount extends Account {
private int interesi;
public SavingAccount(int a, int interesi){
    super(a);    
    this.interesi = interesi;
}
```

Comment: using its public getter/setter method, which it hopefully has

Comment: Please [search first](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F+java+access+super+private+field)

Comment: If you're in a position to change the `Account` class, you can declare the variable `protected` instead. Otherwise, the author probably made it private for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use getters and setters, or use the `protected` accessibility which allows access by subclasses.